# Recommendation for (LDAP / AD) based Forum

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I’m looking to set up a forum at work. I want to pull staff log-ins from our staff SQL. I was wondering if you recommend any good instances.

thanks in advance

Comment: What are you asking exactly?  Are you trying to setup a forum using LDAP?  Or a forum using SQL?

Comment: I want to set up a forum that can look to our SQL based employee db for user login. My understanding is that I will need either LDAP or AD to do this

Comment: If you want to use a relational database for user login, you don't need LDAP or AD.

Answer (score 0):

phpbb forum supports multiple authentication mechanisms. you could also write your own auth plugin.

If you are looking for authentication using external sql tables, have a look at this 
http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2119765

If you are looking for ldap authentication, this configuration steps might be of helpful.
http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=980155
http://wiki.phpbb.com/Authentication_plugins